# Need help working with paypal ipn, Flagging

Tags: post, curl, paypal, get, paypal-ipn

i have my script working, i can process orders. But how do i flag an order trough the ipn. All paypal says is:

http://www.paypalobjects.com/en_US/ebook/PP_OrderManagement_IntegrationGuide/ipn.html

```
 "If the secret posted by PayPal does not match the secret that you expect, flag the IPN     for further investigation."
```

Ok but now how do i flag it in the code. do i echo something out?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What that means is to flag it in your own database.  For example, if you're saving all of the IPN data in your system as an Order or something like that, you could want to include a field called something like "potential_fraud" and set it to a 1 if the secret doesn't match.

This way you can set notifications of some sort for people shipping product or whoever might be working with that data so they know to look into it before continuing.